# LinkedHashMap ConcurrentModificationException Error

Tags: java, exception, concurrenthashmap, linkedhashmap, concurrentmodification

In my java program for an MUDRPG there are two threads at the moment (if I'm not mistaken, I didn't write the engine). One thread is purely graphical and displays all of the `Gui` objects, and another thread handles all of the computation. That second thread is the one that handles battles. In my battle code, I'm checking to see if a hitsplat gui exists, however, after a few successful calls to the function (a different number every time), I get stuck with a `ConcurrentModificationException`. This seems to be because at the same time that this battle is trying to check if the hitsplats exist, the graphics thread is attempting to display things from the `LinkedHashMap`. Could someone please instruct me what the proper way of reading from a `LinkedHashMap` is to avoid this issue, or do I need to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead? My understanding is that the `LinkedHashMap` is used because it can handle order, I'm not quite sure if the same holds true for `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Code that accesses the LinkedHashMap on the computation thread:

```
private boolean checkHitsplats(){
    System.out.println("I get called)");
    while (true) {
        try {
            if (OneQuest.getInstance().getTickThread().getGuis()
                    .get("HitsplatPlayer") == null
                    && OneQuest.getInstance().getTickThread().getGuis()
                            .get("HitsplatMonster1") == null
                    && OneQuest.getInstance().getTickThread().getGuis()
                            .get("HitsplatMonster2") == null
                    && OneQuest.getInstance().getTickThread().getGuis()
                            .get("HitsplatMonster3") == null) {
                return false; // return false if none exist
            } else
                return true; // return true of any hitsplats exist
        } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
            System.out.println("modification error");
        }
    }
}
```

A snippet of the code that cycles through the linkedHashMap to display graphics items, where `guis` is a LinkedHashMap with all of the graphics objects added.

```
private void tick() {
    synchronized (guis) {
        Iterator<Gui> iter = guis.values().iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Gui gui = iter.next();
            if (gui.isShowing()) {
                gui.render(window);
            }
        }
    }
    if (guiConsole.isShowing()) {
        guiConsole.render(window);
    }
}
```

Edit: Version 2 of checkHitsplats as suggested by a kind person.

```
private boolean checkHitsplats(){
    Object[] guis = OneQuest.getInstance().getTickThread().getGuis().values().toArray();
    System.out.println("I get called)");

    while (true) {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < guis.length; i++) {
                if (((Gui) guis[i]).getGuiName() == "HitsplatPlayer"
                        || ((Gui) guis[i]).getGuiName() == "HitsplatMonster1"
                        || ((Gui) guis[i]).getGuiName() == "HitsplatMonster2"
                        || ((Gui) guis[i]).getGuiName() == "HitsplatMonster3")
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please try to use: Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap()). Please refer link below for more information:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're comparing strings with `==`! You should not do that (even if it might work in your specific case, it's a dangerous habit to get into).

Comment: You need to give more info: how do you instantiate the map (insertion or access order)? On what line is the exception thrown (check the exception message)?

Comment: You shouldn't get this exception unless you are modifying your map at the same time somewhere, especially not in your `checkHitsplats()` method which is not even iterating the map. Are you sure this is where the exception is thrown? Can you post your stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

A `ConcurrentHashMap` won't throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` when iterating over it, but as you noted it does not keep track of key order. Another option is to iterate over `LinkedHashMap#values.toArray()` or `LinkedHashMap#entrySet.toArray()` - `toArray` will make a copy of the collection, and so iterating over the array it returns won't throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: Hmm ... how does the syntax for that work, exactly? Assuming I have a LinkedHashMap called guis, would it be: `LinkedHashMap#guis.toArray()`?

Comment: It would be `Object[] array = guis.values().toArray()` or `Object[] array = guis.entrySet().toArray()`. If `guis` is a generic map, e.g. `LinkedHashMap<K, V> guis`, then you can use `V[] array = guis.values().toArray(new V[])` or `Map.Entry<K,V>[] array = guis.entrySet().toArray(new Map.Entry<K,V>[])`

Comment: I implemented your suggestion but I'm still getting the same issue. Please check updated OP for new code.

Comment: You can't get a `ConcurrentModificationException` when iterating over an array. Is there another piece of code that's iterating over the `LinkedHashMap`? Bear in mind that any for-each loop that iterates over the `LinkedHashMap` may throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`